# getopt returns 0 exit status for unrecognized option

Tags: linux, bash, getopt

The Unix man page for getopt states

> If there are problems parsing the parameters, for example because a required argument is not found or an option is not recognized, an error will be reported on stderr, there will be no output for the
> offending element, and a non-zero error status is returned.

However, in my shell (GNU Bash 5.2.15):

```
$ getopt --long foo -- --bar
 --
$ echo $?
0
```

In other words, getopt returned 0 (success) even though it was given an unrecognized option "--bar".  Shouldn't getopt return a non-zero exit status in this case?

Answer (score 1):

In that invocation, `getopt` was not given an unrecognised option. It was not given any option, because `--bar`, being the first parameter, was interpreted as an optstring, as indicated in [man 1 getopt](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getopt.1.html):

> If no `-o` or `--options` option is found in the first part, the first parameter of the second part is used as the short options string.

After that, there were no parameters left, which is perfectly legal.

Since the optstring is a positional parameter, and therefore not optional, you must specify an empty optstring explicitly, for example as `''`, if you really don't want to recognise any short options:

```bash
$ getopt --long foo -- '' --bar
getopt: unrecognized option '--bar'
 --
$ echo $?
1
```

I know that this doesn't seem entirely consistent with the description of the `-o` option to `getopt`, but that description is internally inconsistent, since it clearly indicates that an optstring *can* start with a `-` (meaning that `getopt` should emit non-option parameters immediately, which makes it a lot harder to interpret the return value). I believe that what was meant was "the first parameter of `getopt` *in the first part of the command line*".

Comment: THanks, but what if I don’t want to specify _any_ short options?